# prettyphoto youtube full screen not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

in my page i added prettyphoto for iframe and youtube link. but now issue is in YouTube link section fullscreen option not working it is said **"full screen is unavailable"** but if i use **Lity - Lightweight responsive lightbox** then full screen work. but as lity lightbox have limitation for window size i do not use.

HTML

```
<a href="http://xxxxx.com/video-popup/?vpid=46&amp;iframe=true&amp;width=600&amp;height=320" rel="prettyPhotov[iframes]" title=" Hotel Granvia Kyoto" class="flaticon-film51"></a>
```

JS

```
 $(".videoiteam a[rel^='prettyPhotov']").prettyPhoto({

      overlay_gallery: false,

      theme: 'dark_square',

      social_tools: false,

      slideshow:false, 

      show_title: false

      });
```

attached is image for [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to add `allowfullscreen` attribute to `iframe_markup` property:

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
    overlay_gallery: false,
    show_title: false,
    hideflash: true,
    social_tools: "", 
    iframe_markup: "<iframe src='{path}' width='{width}' height='{height}' frameborder='no' allowfullscreen='true'></iframe>", 
    deeplinking: false
});

.....

<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vh0mGLpbIvI" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/Vh0mGLpbIvI/default.jpg"></a>
```